# Why does not the css property take effect?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I just want the logo to get centered, and every time when i apply the 'align-items: center;' it does not take effect, where's the problem guys ?

```css
#logo {
  flex: 1 1 40rem;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="head_main">
  <nav>
    <h1 id="logo">travelly</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#locations">locations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#benefits">benefits</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Would clarify more how you want the logo to be centered ?

Comment: I think text-align: center;  might solve your problem

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what the significance of the 40rem is?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: text-align center, or <nav> ``display:flex`` ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the significance of the 40rem in the flex setting is, but if it is saying 'allocate the h1 40rem' then one way of specifying this is to set its width to 40rem and use the 'old fashioned' margin auto to center the div.

```css
#logo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="head_main">
  <nav>
    <h1 id="logo">travelly</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#locations">locations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#benefits">benefits</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```